# Database do I need to de-normalize a related field?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I have two tables in my database:

- Package

  Contains all information about package, such as tracking, weight.
- Shipment

  Contains list of arrived to warehouse packages that are being shipped. With status attribute:

  in_transit, delayed, customs, delivered

**Question is:**
Users are able to view their packages and I am showing them current package status by querying it from shipment that package belongs to.
Do I need to make **shipment_status** column on Package table, and when updating the shipment status, run query updating that column of each package? Or current solution is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to.  When you need the shipment status, you can do a join if you really want to do one query of Packages and include the shipment status.

For example,

```
Packages.joins(:shipment).where(user_id: current_user.id).select('packages.*, shipments.status as shipment_status')
```

This would be a replacement for

```
current_user.packages
```

With the join, you would have a `Package` object with a `shipment_status` method.

Comment: Is it okay to query in view like this: `<% if package.shipment %> <%= package.shipment.status %> <% else %> <%= package.delivery_status %><% end %>` (Package.delivery_status is about package arrived to warehouse or not)

Comment: Yes that is perfectly OK.  However, it might do a separate query to the database whenever you call `.shipment`.  Just be careful and use eager loading when appropriate.